# Typescript: Partial<MyType> with sub-properties to optional

Tags: typescript, types, conditional-statements, partial

Is it possible, in typescript, to let a method accept `Partial<Something>`, in a way that `Something`'s sub-properties are all set to optional too?

```
export interface ISomething {
    user: IUser;
}
export interface IUser {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

export const myMethod = (something: Partial<ISomething>): void => {};

myMethod({ user: { id: 1, name: "" } });   //this works

myMethod({ user: { id: 1 } });             //this doesn't (but I want this to work too)
```

many thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

You are essentially looking for some sort of deep partial mapped type, something like

```js
 type DeepOptional<T> = T extends object
    ? DeepOptionalObject<T>
    : T | undefined

type DeepOptionalObject<T> = { [P in keyof T]?: DeepOptional<T[P]> }

type Foo = { bar: Bar }
type Bar = { a: number, b: boolean[] }

const f1: Partial<Foo> = { bar: { a: 1 } } // NOPE
const f2: DeepOptional<Foo> = { bar: {a: 1 } } // OK
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=53#code/AQFwngDgpsAiVQgeQiAlgewHYEMA2APACoB8wAvMEcFAB4hRYAmAzsBgEYBWUAxiAFgAUMFHAA-HATJUmXHiTc+IYiWFjgALirAAPsACuzKADM0WKE2HDw0KYhTps+RT36qKwAN7AA2gAVgc2AAaygwDBMqAF1xbXgHWWdCIgDosgBfayFbGAAxDAxPHw4cACdtACFy4CycyBhqsuLgHG0sAwBbDigygBpgDm0OQrwoHCxfaNrs3mwWEGATAEZtf3L0fAICjDJKEvLtHzbgZdrzgHoL4AA5JH8AUWE5rAWlgCZ46Uc5LZ297yDQ7eE5nDKXa5IADSQA)

Comment: could you also take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60973387/typescript-tell-methods-parameter-to-accept-only-t-as-exact-string