# Tell method's parameter to accept only <T> as exact string

Tags: typescript, conditional-statements

I'd like to have something like this:

```
SomeAbsClass.getSomething<IMyType>("IMyType");
```

So, how to I code `getSomething`'s parameter so it'll only accept the exact "IMyType" as string?

There's something to do with Conditional types, in the same vein as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60762168/typescript-partialmytype-with-sub-properties-to-optional/60762634#60762634), but I can't figure it out.

Comment: What are you trying to *achieve* here? If the parameter is just the name of the generic type, what's the use of it?

Answer (score 2):

There's no inherent relationship in TypeScript between [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) (like `"IMyType"`) and the names of named types (like `IMyType`).  String literal types represent actual string values which exist at runtime, while type names respresent aspects of the static type system which is completely [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) from the emitted JavaScript.

Furthermore, the type system is [structural](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing), not nominal, so the *names* of types don't really matter much.   If I declare

```
type IYourType = IMyType;
```

then `IYourType` and `IMyType` are just two different names for the same type.  And therefore if `SomeAbsClass.getSomething<IYourType>("IYourType");` succeeds, then `SomeAbsClass.getSomething<IMyType>("IYourType");` should *also* succeed.

There's no principled way to force the type system to decide that one name is more "canonical" than another, so that `SomeAbsClass.getSomething<IMyType>("IMyType");` succeeds and `SomeAbsClass.getSomething<IMyType>("IYourType");` fails automatically.

---

Since this doesn't happen automatically, the closest I can imagine getting here is for you to *manually* build up a type representing the desired mapping between string literals and types, such as:

```
interface TypeMapping {
    IMyType: IMyType;
    Date: Date;
    string: string;
    boolean: boolean;
    // add whatever you want
}
```

and then use that mapping in your definition of `getSomething()`, like this

```
declare const SomeAbsClass: {
    getSomething<T>(x: {
        [K in keyof TypeMapping]: TypeMapping[K] extends T ? K : never }[keyof TypeMapping]
    ): void;
}
```

And you call it like this (making sure to explicitly specify the generic type parameter when you do so):

```
SomeAbsClass.getSomething<IMyType>("IMyType"); // okay
SomeAbsClass.getSomething<IMyType>("IYourType"); // error
```

That works as far as it goes.  Whether it fits your use case is another story.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOECydOagDmyA3gFDJXICSO6G2AXLfYxANyXUAickLPpC7VkAZzBRiLCVJBER1AEYB7FQBsIcEC1UatIDsm5UA9KeRwAJleQB3ABb8IAN2jJ0KgK73tYcgC+5ORWEAjqcFAoCCogEsgAyioAthAAgkpiAMIRYmIsFKJEEGBJqWAOxAA8qAB8ABQAHgUmosgA2gDSyKDIANYQnjBoWLj4hPIAuizseATEXZPIEI2QIFZiaMgA-MjdLCCu7gHtA0Mj2HMTRJOtAJQsLirAVlxB5KCQsIgodAyjZFacBkkmIb2CZXSmRycDyADpiqUUiVKvIqn92A0AEQY0ZYu5GczIFR9ODoYJgAE0ACa3ig7GQAF5WP9sFxyJCMtlcmIESVIRVqrjsNiaXT2PjCRZoFAVFByEA)

Comment: ok, so, there's no way to let TypeMapping's properties be dynamic? That's the main point, you see. It's pretty bad, but I got typescript's behavior does not allow... Thank you for your time!